# JSTL c:choose issue

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I need to implement a switch case using JSTL choose statement, I have tree different choise.
Anyone knows the reason why the code below doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type}==0">
        <option selected="selected">Carta di Identità</option>
        <option>Passaporto</option>
        <option>Patente di Guida</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type}==1">
        <option>Carta di Identità</option>
        <option selected="selected">Passaporto</option>
        <option>Patente di Guida</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type}==2">
        <option>Carta di Identità</option>
        <option>Passaporto</option>
        <option selected="selected">Patente di Guida</option>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <option>Scegli...</option>
        <option>Carta di Identità</option>
        <option>Passaporto</option>
        <option>Patente di Guida</option>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: If you print out the expression '${iUserInfo.identification_card_type}', will you get a result? As far as I know, '== 1' should be enough.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work, I think is it not enough.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't evaluate the **entire** expression inside `${}`. Fix it accordingly:

```
<c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type == 0}">
...
<c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type == 1}">
...
<c:when test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type == 2}">
```

Comment: Then it doesn't return an `int` at all. If it actually returns `String`, then you need to fix it accordingly so that it returns `int`. Or if you can't due to some (stupid) business restrictions, then change `0`, `1`, `2`, etc in the expressions to `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, etc.

Comment: iUserInfo.identification_card_type is a long value. I also use '1' and '2' , '3' but it is still not working

Comment: Then it doesn't return those values. Put `${iUserInfo.identification_card_type}` right before the `<c:choose>` to see what it *actually* returns. If it doesn't show anything, then the fault is in the model code. If it shows the right values, then the fault is in JSTL setup.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,

I usually use this kind of test:

```
test="${iUserInfo.identification_card_type eq 0}"
```

Instead of normal comparison you should use the jstl's ones, like gt (greater then), st (smaller then) and eq, that means equals.
Keep going, jstl and servlet they rock!